# SPARQL Dbpedia get value is....of

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

i want to make a dataset about Indonesian actor and film they starred in
This is my query to get their names and other property

```
select distinct ?Nama ?Tempat_Lahir { 
?s dcterms:subject <http://id.dbpedia.org/resource/Kategori:Aktor_Indonesia>.
?s rdfs:label ?Nama.
?s dbpprop-id:birthplace ?Tempat_Lahir.
}
```

in the resource page (ex : http://id.dbpedia.org/page/Ashraf_Sinclair) it have **is dbpprop-id:starring of** which is the movie they starred, how to get this value into my queries ?

Comment: "... is of " in the DBpedia view means the reverse direction, i.e. position of subject and object have been switched. So, RDF has directed relations, and clearly it depends on the knowledge base how a relation is expressed. One could state "personX hasBirthPlace placeY" or "placeY birthPlaceOf personX" - the same information expressed differently. And often you just find one direction in the KB. So it's your turn to figure out which one. In your case, you want to add a triple pattern `?film dbpedia-owl:starring ?s .`